# R conditional variable replacement in dataframe

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I need to recode variable (column) values in a dataframe. The following snippet replaces my values with what looks like array indexes instead of the categorial values:

```
CMlist <- c("CMdysphagiascreen","CMStrokeUnit","CMVTE","CMantithromd2")
for (i in CMlist) {
    RHSSP[[i]] <- ifelse(RHSSP[[i]] == "NDOC", "Y", RHSSP[[i]])
    RHSSP[[i]] <- ifelse(RHSSP[[i]] == "U", "N", RHSSP[[i]])
    RHSSP[[i]] <- ifelse(is.NULL(RHSSP[[i]]), "N", RHSSP[[i]])
}
```

No doubt there's a better method for doing this. Can someone explain what's wrong with my attempt and maybe a better way of going about it?

Comment: For starters, your code fails because `is.NULL` is not a function.

Comment: `RHSSP[[i]][ RHSSP[[i]] ==  "NDOC" ] <- "Y"` and `RHSSP[[i]][ RHSSP[[i]] ==  "U" ]    <- "N"` and `RHSSP[[i]][ is.na(RHSSP[[i]]) ]     <- "N"` should be the lines inside your loop.

Comment: Also, do you have `factor` values or `character` values in your `RHSSP` `data.frame`? If factor, you'll want to run `as.character` on those columns first like `RHSSP$var <- as.character(RHSSP$var)`

Comment: The basic problem is that the variables you're changing are factors and factors cannot be assigned arbitrary values. You need to create a new set of factors with the appropriate levels, e.g. `"Y"` and `"N"`. Also, it's  highly recommended that you include a minimal working example when asking a question.